# Перекодировать текст из UTF-8 в CP-1251 с htmlentities

Tags: php, utf-8, cp1251, iconv

Есть тексты в формате utf-8, они включают в себя уникальные символы (например польского языка: ą ę ż etc.). Как мне их перекодировать в cp-1251 с минимальными потерями?
Я имею ввиду закодировать уникальные символы в html сущности (например: ξ ζ ).

Мой код выглядит так:

```
$outputText = str_replace(
    array('&lt;', '&gt;'),
    array('<', '>'),
    htmlentities(
        iconv( "utf-8", DEFAULT_CHARSET, $inputText),
        ENT_NOQUOTES,
        DEFAULT_CHARSET
    )
);
```

P.S. Я слышал о возможности выводить на страницах с кодировкой cp-1251 блоки в иной кодировке - UTF-8, например. Как это сделать? И поможет ли это мне?

Comment: А зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: Просто никогда не пользуйтесь неюникодными кодировками. Проблема решена!

Comment: @VladD в редких случаях следует держаться в стороне от юникода.

Comment: Только для того что бы удовлетворить Ваш интерес. Есть сайт старушка которому 15 лет. Времени переписывать его нету (Поменять только кодировки не представляется возможным) необходимо переписывать весь движок (так как он завязан внутри на кодеровки). Есть у сайта поддомен на UTF-8. SEO-шник сказал что под домен переезжает в основной сайт мы делаем.